# How to fix 'Argument out of range exception' in my code?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to match a column of dataGridView (dataGridViewLAS) and a list (TransitTime) but the exception is:

> Index was out of range. most be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection.

```
for (int i = 0; i < DataGridViewLAS.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (DataGridViewLAS[3, i].Value != null)
    {
        TPorosity.TransitTime = new List<double>
        {
            [i] = Convert.ToDouble(DataGridViewLAS[3, i].Value)
        };
    }
}
```

I saw the similar questions but cannot fix the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we did not know the current state of your `DataGridViewLAS[3, i]` we could only assume that the 4 columns within your [`DataGridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.8) exists. If not, this will cause the exception.

---

The next possibility where this exception could occur, is the following code:

```
TPorosity.TransitTime = new List<double>
{
     [i] = Convert.ToDouble(DataGridViewLAS[3, i].Value)
};
```

You want to address an index, which is not available in the current state of your `List<double>`.

---

I must admit, it is the first time I saw this usage of an object initializer for a list.
So I tested, if it is possible to use this with an index of 0 when adding it to a list with an defined capacity like:

```
var test = new List<double>(4)
{
    [0] = 2.0
};
```

But this will also raise the:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
>   Parameter name: index
>     + System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(System.ExceptionArgument, System.ExceptionResource)
>     + List.set_Item(int, T)

---

*Site note:*

*It also looks suspicious, that you always create a new list for your `TPorosity.TransitTime`.*

*I guess you just want to add the an element to the `List<double>`. 
For that, you could assign the `new List<double>` before your for loop and use*

```
Add(Convert.ToDouble(DataGridViewLAS[3, i].Value)
```

*If it is necessary to hold the correct order/position of the value. You may have to pre-fill the list with default values for the size of your row count.*

Answer (score 0):

Either `3` or `i` is outside of the range of the `DataGridViewLAS`. You'd need to have an `if` statement before doing `DataGridViewLAS[3, i]`, to check whether it has enough values in it.

Comment: thanks! Can you tell me exactly how I use if for check it?

Comment: Something to check first is whether your code is doing what you think it should be doing. You are trying to get the 4th row of the `DataGridViewLAS`. Does this have 4 rows?

Answer (score -1):

```
var doubleList = new List<double>(DataGridViewLAS.Rows.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < DataGridViewLAS.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (DataGridViewLAS.ColumnCount >3 && DataGridViewLAS[3, i].Value != null)
            {
                doubleList.Add(Convert.ToDouble(DataGridViewLAS[3, i].Value));
            }
        }
```

you should don't use object initilaze when List createing